# DynamoDB Query in GSI with FilterExpression

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to perform a query in a GSI with Filter Expression but AWS keeps telling me that is not finding the expression.
The query is the following:

```
var tableQuery = {
        TableName: "posts",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#wy = :wkYr",
        FilterExpression: "#ac = :isAct",
        IndexName: "weekYear-date-index",
        ScanIndexForward: false,
        Limit: 50,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#wy": "weekYear",
            "#ac": "isActive"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":wkYr": cWeekYear,
            ":isAct": {BOOL: true}
        }
    };
```

and the error shown:

```
An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :isAct
```

I've been trying different approaches but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Console Log of the current query:

```
 {
  "TableName": "posts",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "#wy = :wkYr",
  "FilterExpression": "#ac = :isAct",
  "IndexName": "weekYear-date-index",
  "ScanIndexForward": false,
  "Limit": 50,
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#wy": "weekYear",
    "#ac": "isActive"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":wkYr": 2040,
    ":isAct": {
      "BOOL": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) ? if not then the issue might be the attributeValue isn't defined as bool.

Comment: Are you saying to do this: `":isAct": {BOOL: true}`  and yes I am using this for querying: `var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();`

Comment: Yeah if you are using the AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient then your usage is correct in the question post, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Ok, I really don't understand why this is happening cause all the examples are like this and really not knowing what is going on

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: Since you're using the DocumentClient you don't need to specify the ":isAct": {BOOL: true}, the DocumentClient wont accept AttributeValues in place of javascript types.  Sorry for the confusion, really just needed to clarify if you were doing dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() or dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB()

Comment: I've tried both and its still the same

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should pass in your value
`":isAct": true`

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, ty for contributing. You may consider to make the [tour] and for this answer maybe improve it with some explanations. Also have a look here: [How to Answer]